# negation / inversion of python pandas DataFrame.filter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I filter columns of a data frame not containing a given string in their label?

[DataFrame.filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) allows, for example, to select all columns of a data frame whose label contain a provided string.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array(([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])),
    columns=['beat', 'meat', 'street']
)
df.filter(like="eat", axis=1) ### yields the columns "beat" and "meat".
```

Is there a way to revert this logic, so that I may only keep those columns not containing "eat"? Alternatively: Is there a way to drop columns containing "eat"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regex` parameter:

```
print (df.filter(regex=r'^(?!.*eat).*$'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @jezrael's answer, one could parameterize the solution like this:

```py
import re
def neg_filter(df, not_like, axis):
    """Only keep labels from axis, which satisfy `not_like in label == False`."""
    pattern = r"^(?!.*" + re.escape(not_like) + r").*$"
    return df.filter(regex=pattern, axis=axis)
```